# Defining my React.js state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a working React app (no Redux or Flux, yet) which I like to improve. I am a bit confused with my state at the moment. It seems more complicated than it needs to be including some redundancy.

I am building a dart game (Tactics a.k.a. cricket) in which two players hit numbers on the dartboard. Hitting a number three times completes the number. You can score points on a number if your opponent has not completed it yet.

Since I only want to show an 'add points' button for a number if the active player has completed it and the opponent not yet, The active player needs to know the completed status of the opponent for a given number.

My state at the moment looks like this:

```
data: {
  startTurn: false,
  gameFinished: false,
  player1: {
    name: 'Player 1',
    roundsWon: 0,
    turn: false,
    score: {
        '20': {hits: 2, completed: true},
        '19': {hits: 3, completed: true},
        '18': {hits: 3, completed: true},
        '17': {hits: 3, completed: true},
        '16': {hits: 4, completed: true},
        '15': {hits: 5, completed: true},
        '14': {hits: 3, completed: true},
        '13': {hits: 4, completed: true},
        '12': {hits: 3, completed: true},
        '11': {hits: 3, completed: true},
        '10': {hits: 3, completed: true}
    }
  },
  player2: {
    name: 'Player 2',
    roundsWon: 0,
    turn: true,
    score: {
        '20': {hits: 4, completed: false},
        '19': {hits: 4, completed: true},
        '18': {hits: 3, completed: true},
        '17': {hits: 3, completed: true},
        '16': {hits: 3, completed: true},
        '15': {hits: 3, completed: true},
        '14': {hits: 3, completed: true},
        '13': {hits: 3, completed: true},
        '12': {hits: 3, completed: true},
        '11': {hits: 3, completed: true},
        '10': {hits: 3, completed: true}
    }
  }
}
```

I think that in particular the 'score' part for the players could be defined better, but I'm not sure how. I did read on the normalize, but somehow my state did not seem to fit in.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Structure looks fine to me. The only data redundancy is probably the turn (if it is`true` for player 1, then probably it must be `false` for player 2). The only redundancy is in structure, but that is best managed with objects anyway (player object: 2 instances, score object: 11 instances per player).

Comment: @wintvelt, you are right, the turn is indeed redundant, I could remove it from the player's object. I don't really understand your point on the redundancy in structure though, I am using objects, right?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I mean is: if you spell out all the data like you do, it may look redundant (e.g. with 22 'hits' and 22 'completed' fields). But your structure is OK: you define one object `score` or something, and simply create 2 x 11 instances.

Comment: Alright, thx for the clarification. I have been thinking more about this the last days and think I just need the score object as defined.